# Permission error and schemas error in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, intellisense

I tried to make my IntelliSense work with axml files. I don`t really know how Xamarin developers made it possible to not work but I still can`t make my IntelliSense work with axml. I tried a lot of pieces of advice (including https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1920119-how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-android-axml-files- ). When I realised this 2 schemas are missed in my Xamarin (I don`t know how but it is popular problem) I downloaded them from https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen but I didn`t have any positive results. My IntelliSense doesn`t work with axml even in XML Editor.
Now I have errors like on the screenshot below. Could you help me to solve this problems and to make IntelliSense work with axml?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Build your design in Android Studio paste it after done in your VS . And dude you just are receiving warnings,most of the times you will be fine even with them, though this behavior is not entertained

Comment: @RahulJha do you know how to solve this warnings?